# Помогите с созданием логических моделей для БД

Tags: sql

У меня проблема с созданием логических моделей для БД. К примеру когда дают темы к примеру логическая модель для БД, позволяющей зарегистрировать **темы курсовых проектов** (рандомный пример).
Возникает сложность как придумывать таблицы для этой БД.
Можете дать советы, инструкцию или что-то еще. Хочу полностью это освоить, может что-то еще нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советы в рандомном порядке, которые когда-то помогали мне при изучении реляционных баз данных.

- Продумывайте объекты и ищите связи — это главное. Допустим, у вас есть курсовые. Задайте вопрос: что есть у курсовой, какие у неё свойства? Тема, естественно. Предмет? Надо вам хранить предмет или в базе курсовые только по одному предмету? Надо хранить студентов, которые взяли темы? А преподавателей, у которых они идут? А номер курса? А группу? Правильных ответов на эти вопросы не существует, это зависит от проекта. Если вам дали задание в стиле «чувак, задизайни нам базу курсовых, да побыстрее!», правильным будет послать… за дополнительными сведениями, даже если это препод и надо это делать крайне вежливо. «Обрисуйте, пожалуйста, требования к базе». Допустим, у вас полная фантазия и никто ничего не хочет говорить. Делайте по максимуму (да, я знаю про принцип YAGNI, но, если честно, его недолюбливаю, и частенько я таки оказывался прав и надобилось то, что не нужно было раньше).
- Рассматривайте каждый объект, у которого есть более одного свойства, как повод для создания новой таблицы. Например: что такое предмет в нашем случае? Если это некое перечисление, то и ладно, пусть это будет полем таблицы «Курсовые». А если нам нужно связать предмет, например, с преподавателем, то всё, это уже новая таблица предметов.
- У каждой таблицы должен быть идентификатор, первичный ключ. Комментаторам: Я знаю, что это необязательно, но человек начинающий, а лично мне это сильно помогло систематизировать всё в голове в своё время. Так вот, по первичному ключу (это положительное целое число, которое автоматически увеличивается при добавлении строк в таблицу, — проще говоря, номер записи), можно быстро искать данные, по нему же можно и нужно связывать объекты. Например: если у нас предметы — это всё же таблица, то в нашей таблице «Курсовые» будет поле `subject_id`, которое будет связано с помощью `FOREIGN KEY` с таблицей предметов, точнее, с её первичным ключом.
- Обобщайте, если это возможно. Если у вас есть студенты и преподаватели, их можно поместить в одну таблицу, ибо и те, и те — люди (не предметы, не курсовые, не темы и не стулья, скажем). соответственно, раз они люди, у них большинство полей одинаковое: имя, фамилия, эл. почта, что-то ещё. Тогда отличаться будет поле `status`, например: студент или преподаватель. При этом тут дизайн уже может быть разный: если сведения таки сильно отличаются (у студента есть курс и номер группы, а у препода — предмет и кафедра, допустим), тогда есть смысл или развести их по разным таблицам, или завести отдельную таблицу «Люди» с общими для всех сведениями (ФИО, дата рождения, эл. почта, телефон), а потом добавить малюсенькие таблички «Студенты» и «Преподаватели», в которых по сути только связывать все объекты по айдишникам (например, таблица преподов: первичный ключ, ID человека из таблицы людей, ID предмета из таблицы предметов и т.д., и т.п.). Тогда вы сможете делать любые запросы, например: «А дай-ка мне, дорогой SQL, всех преподавателей английского и всех, кто пишет у них курсовые, да ещё и сгруппируй студентов по преподавателю».
- Вопреки предыдущему пункту: старайтесь не раздувать таблицы по числу полей (колонок). Если видите, что их много, желательно с этим что-то делать. Звучит слишком расплывчато, но и совет этот такой… не все и не всегда ему следуют.

Comment: Очень подозреваю, что это его курсовая и требование там только одно - не менее 20 (или 50) таблиц в базе (возможно, не считая таблиц связей).

Comment: @Andre Polykanine Спасибо большое! Нужно будет много практиковаться.